# How to encode string and array to json in php

Tags: php, json

I have some data from database which is like:

```
$name= "xxx";
$title= "xxx";
$arrayGender = array("Boy","Girl");
$arrayName = array("John", "Rosy");
```

How do I encode the data to a json object, so i guess the json would be something like:

```
{ 
  "name":"xxx",
  "title":"xxx",
  "children":[{"Boy","John"},{"Girl","Rosy"}]
}
```

Comment: Try json_encode to encode the data and set the content-type with header('Content-type: application/json');

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object and set your target data in it. Then use [**`json_encode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to converting php object into json.

```php
$name= "xxx";
$title= "xxx";
$arrayGender = array("Boy","Girl");
$arrayName = array("John", "Rosy");

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->name = $name;
$obj->title = $title;
$obj->children = [$arrayGender, $arrayName];

echo json_encode($obj);
```

Check the code in [demo](https://3v4l.org/o81QV)